# Please unlock question, as will be resolved

Tags: discussion

meta!

I had my story wrong, which was bringing problems (extended discussions) in [my question, "How often does a propeller vane break off?"](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/99525/69467).

I contacted the MAF directly, and a more accurate story came out that is believable, and should cause less contention.

Please unlock the question, and I will add the more accurate story, and commit to not having extended discussions.

Here's the info I received, which I would like to add as an edit to the question:

> I was unable to verify your uncle’s propeller accident, but when
> asking around, one person remembered a similar story but it involved
> John flying a Cessna 185 in Africa where he lost a propeller tip (no
> welding involved). In order to fly the plane to an MAF repair base, he
> reportedly sawed the other propeller blade down to match the shorter
> one and it flew reasonably well out of the jungle until it could get
> properly fixed—no third blade involved. Of course, this cannot be
> confirmed, nor did it comply with MAF standards of safety, and it was
> 60 + years ago.

Someone said in comments that this could have happened, so I know that it would be better received.

Please allow me to wrap up the story.

Thank you for considering my request.

Note: if this is using meta incorrectly, please help me to go through the right channels and do the right things so as to be a good citizen here. Thank you.

If you want to re-lock after I add the final story, that's fine, but probably won't be necessary. Thanks again.

Comment: Or should I just ask a new question?

Comment: No, it's unlocked. That update sounds good. Just, please don't add the multiple-deleted comment -- that was a little incendiary (as well as pretty far removed from Aviation subject matter). It sounds like the update you got will wrap things up nicely, while preserving the (not uninteresting) answers regarding, *could* somebody weld a prop blade in that manner?  Thanks for posting this question here in Meta.

Comment: As a thought, might work well to post that update as an answer, and leave the question basically where it stands. Or tweak it to "could this (welding a blade) work", which is basically what the answers are all answering anyway.

Comment: @RalphJ - Do you mean change the title of the question to "Can you use a welder to move a propeller blade from 120 degrees to 180? "  Does that work?

Comment: @RalphJ -- Done!

Comment: Looks good - nice improvement to the thread, wraps things up nicely.